# window.open("\\\\localhost\\"); not working on win7(x64) ie8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, windows-7-x64, window.open

`window.open("\\\\localhost\\");` is not working on ie8 on 64bit win7. ie says "make sure the path or internet address is correct". it's working on same verson of ie8 on 32 bit. any idea? or any different way to access a path like `\\localhost\` using internet explorer?

i'm trying to open `\\localhost` like a file path. when you write `\\localhost` on ie, it opens "Network > localhost"

In error details, ie says "Message: Access is denied.".

It may related to security settings of windows. Any idea which settings of windows might cause that?

Comment: ``\localhost\`` does not look like a valid URL. Have you tried `http://localhost` ?

Comment: i'm trying to open \\localhost like a file path. when you write \\localhost on ie it opens "Network > Localhost"

Comment: Try `file://localhost` but this may not be possible any more due to security reasons

Comment: `file://localhost` gives same error on 64 bit. and it's also works on 32 bit windows.

Comment: may that be related to security settings? accessing files or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running httpd in your host http://localhost/... must work.
Otherwise, better use file:///... to access local file.
I don't know how come \\localhost\... did work for your 32bit machine.
Maybe, IE 8 script engine did interpret that as a simple file path, and then tried to access the path from local SMB server. Did you enabled windows file sharing as you did in 32bit machine?
Anyway I do not believe that URL scheme is compatible with other browsers than IE.

Comment: i'm trying to open `\\localhost` like a file path. when you write `\\localhost` on ie, it opens "Network > Localhost"

Comment: OK, and what about Javascript here? It's question about the settings of your OS, not about 'javascript' and not about 'window.open'.

Comment: Ok than any idea which settings of windows might cause that?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. When I type \\localhost\ in IE adress input, I got some error like "Cannot find file://localhost/". Instead, when I type \\shrws3\ , which is my computer's windows share name, network neighbourhood window opens as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

It's worked when I add the site to "Trusted Sites" on ie.

Answer (score 0):

Localhost requires a port number. Open the target site in the browser and get the map path. It should follow the syntax below;

```
                         port #/View Name   /.cshtml file
```

window.open('http://localhost:****/SomeViewName/Some.cshtmlfile', '_blank' + ***.start);